# Convert JSON to Mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, json, data-conversion

I'm trying to convert an JSON data file into MySQL database with some kind of web or script that make me the change.
Somebody know any? or how i can do the change instead?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you looking for something like this http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/convertJsonToSQL.html